# Chrome Extension: Unable to resize Panel

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, panel

I am creating a window of type `panel` but no matter what size I set it does not get changed. Is it possible to change it? Code is given below:

```
chrome.windows.create({
            url: "panel.html",
            type: "panel",
            focused: true,
            width: 800,//does not work
            height: 500 // does not work
          },
```

Check this current size:
[image]

Comment: Do you have the experimental panel type enabled?

Comment: @Xan Yes, and this is why it shows in form of Panel

Comment: Have you tried resizing them after creation, from the code?

Comment: @Xan No. Can you elaborate it how to do it?

Comment: `window.resizeTo(width, height)` from the panel itself.

Comment: So I write this code within .js file that is called from `panel.html`?

Answer (score 0):

Panels seem to have a maximum size of half the screen. If I create a panel of `screen.width`, the result is the same as `screen.width / 2`, but `screen.width / 3` results in a panel that is a third of my screen. It also isn't possible to drag the panel to be more than half the screen width. The only way to get a floating window is to have users install a separate chrome app. They can use [External Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external), and the app can create maximized floating windows using the [alwaysOnTop](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#type-CreateWindowOptions) window creation option.

Comment: They are not even half of screen. Check the screen I added in original question.

Comment: I don't understand how that impacts the fact that panels won't take up the whole screen.